How to make custom cache key prefix for every subpage in django?
Imagine, that we can add slug in cache_page decorator for every view:
#urls.py
...
path('vacancy/<slug:slug>/', cache_page(60*60*24*7, key_prefix='vacancy_single_<slug:slug>')(views.VacancyDetailView.as_view()), name='vacancy_single'),
...

Then - i will have caches something like this in my redis db:
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page.vacancy_single_first-slug.GET.5fe2e..."
2) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header.vacancy_single_second-slug.882f6..."
3) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page.vacancy_single_second-slug.GET.882f6..."
4) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header.vacancy_single_first-slug.5fe2e..."

With that data i can delete cache on exact model's page, when it was updated/deleted using signals:
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Vacancy
import redis


def clear_cache_by_prefix(prefix):
    redis_connection = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379, db=0)
    keys = redis_connection.scan_iter(f'*{prefix}*')
    for key in keys:
        redis_connection.delete(key)


@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Vacancy)
def clear_works_cache(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    prefix = f'vacancy_single_{instance.slug}'
    clear_cache_by_prefix(prefix)

But it is wrong, because i can't use this feature:
cache_page(60*60*24*7, key_prefix='vacancy_single_<slug:slug>')
How i can implement this functionality?
Maybe it is wrong approach, or i need to use special libraries, or caches are not using for that task?
cache_page(60*60*24*7, key_prefix='vacancy_single_<slug:slug>') will return only:
...
2) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page.vacancy/<slug:slug>.GET.5fe2e..."
3) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header.vacancy/<slug:slug>.5fe2e..."
...

